# remote compile and run code directly on raspberry pi 2 with intelij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am developing a robot using raspberry pi 2 in java.
Up until now I was writing the code itself on my pc in InteliJ-IDEA (since its not running smoothly on the pi).
Then I am connecting to the pi with WinSCP in order to sync my project and afterwards I am using putty to compile and run the code remotely thru ssh.

I would like to compile and run the code directly from my PC (with intelij & maven) as that guy does in that [video](https://youtu.be/grItDpy3TRM?t=21m13s).

I searched quite some time for an answer and I couldn't find one.
I would really appreciate if someone could provide me a solution to my problem,
it will save me a lot of time, and I would be able to debug my code efficiently again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found plugin which help a lot.

If you have the same issue as I had, you can download it from that [link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7738?pr=),
or install it directly from the IDE:

settings >> plugins >> browse repositories, and search for "Embedded Linux JVM Debugger".